# Choosing right structuring element

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-morphology

I am creating  an program to  automatically separate the solar cells of from a pv module for which i first thresholded the image using adaptive threshold to obtain the following image

[image: Thresholded image]

After which i intend to remove the the black pixels within the cell boundries by using dilation for which i have used a elliptical structuring element of size (10,10) and have obtained the following image

[image: Thresholded image after dilation (structuring element size (10,10)]

As you can see there are still some black pixels left, now if i increase the size of the structuring element i lose the cell boundaries

[image: Thresholded image after dilation (structuring element size (15,15)]

I have tried the  other structuring elements available such as cross and rectangular without any success hence i would need to define a custom kernel  and don't have an idea  about how  do i go about defining  one.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('result2.jpg',0)
th1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
cv2.THRESH_BINARY,25,-2)
kernel=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(15,15))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(th1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite('closing.jpg',closing)
cv2.imwrite('threshold.jpg',th1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Original image before thresholding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrF7k.jpg)

Comment: I have added the original image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first piece of advice is to not threshold right away. Thresholding is something you want to do way at the end. Thresholding throws away valuable information. Morphological operations work on grey-value images too!

Choosing the right morphological operators to keep only the shapes you are interested in is actually quite intuitive. In this case, you want to keep both horizontal and vertical lines. Let's use line structuring elements. The lines are dark, so we use a closing to remove things that do not look like our lines.

A closing with vertical lines will remove all horizontal lines, and a closing with horizontal lines will remove all vertical lines. So how to combine these two? It turns out that the infimum (pixel-wise minimum) of two closings is a closing also. So the infimum of a closing with vertical lines and one with horizontal lines is a closing with the two lines at the same time, you'll preserve shapes where either of those two lines fit.

Here is an example. I'm using [PyDIP](https://diplib.org) (I don't have OpenCV).

```
import diplib as dip
img = dip.ImageRead('/Users/cris/Downloads/ZrF7k.tif')
img = img.TensorElement(1) # keep only green channel
img = img[0:-2,1:-1]       # let's remove the artifacts at the right and top edges
f1 = dip.Closing(img, dip.SE([50,1],'rectangular'))
f2 = dip.Closing(img, dip.SE([1,50],'rectangular'))
out = dip.Infimum(f1, f2)
out.Show('lin')
```

[image]

You can try to tweak that a bit, and add some additional processing, and add your adaptive thresholding at the end to get the edges of the PV cells. But there is actually a much better way of finding these.

I'm taking advantage here of the fact that the panel is so very straight w.r.t. the image, and that it covers the whole image. We can simply take a mean projection along rows and along columns:

```
x = dip.Mean(out, process=[1, 0]).Squeeze()
y = dip.Mean(out, process=[0, 1]).Squeeze()
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
pp.subplot(2,1,1)
pp.plot(x)
pp.subplot(2,1,2)
pp.plot(y)
pp.show()
```

[image]

It should be fairly straight-forward to detect the edges of the cells from these projections.

Comment: The troughs would correspond to the cell boundaries hence i would require 13 troughs corresponding to columns and 7 troughs corresponding to rows since there are 12 cells along columns and 6 cells along rows.These troughs would be the local minimas, please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @ChirayuThakur yes, that makes sense. You'll have to pick the local minima with highest contrast, not necessarily the lowest values. But some form of local contrast enhancement might make this easier. You can also increase the length on the horizontal line SE to improve the difference between wanted and unwanted minima.